# MQTT message counter on receive

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I tried searching topics related to my question, as I think, it's a quite common to ask.
I wanted to count the number of time the message received on "on_message". The global or local count variable won't work, how to keep count on the received messages?

Here is my snippet of code, where my count won't work as it will reset every time.

def

```
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    ts_data = str(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))
    count=count+1
    print(count)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = mqtt.Client()
    client.on_message=on_message
```

could you help?

Thanks
Kind Regards
Arun

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by the following:

> The global or local count variable won't work,

The following should work just fine:

```
count = 0

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    global count
    ts_data = str(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))
    count=count+1
    print(count)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = mqtt.Client()
    client.on_message=on_message
```

Comment: @arun https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers